# How to dynamically pass an id to url of Bootstrap validator rule: remote for a same form input field?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator, jqbootstrapvalidation, bootstrapvalidator-1000hz

**Bootstrap Validator v 0.5.2** is being re-used for validating form (#myForm) in a modal. 
Need is dynamically pass an unique id (Foreign Key) to 'url' of 'remote' rule when form loads on a modal as below.

```
var remoteUrl = "/remoteurl/";
var id = <Foreign key of the record>

$('#myForm').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        fieldName: {
            validators: {
                remote: {
                    url: remoteUrl + id, //dynamically passing id. // but not passing dynamically.
                    type: 'POST',
                    message: "This is the message!"
                }
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

**Issue:** 
On modal loading, 'id' passes successfully into form dynamically. Though, '**bootstrapValidator**' gets the very first passed 'id' into the form, unless page reloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution!

Add a hidden input field for add the foreign key.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="foreignKey" id="foreignId">
```

And, dynamically pass foreign key to this field.

```
$('#foreignId').val(id);
```

Then, as follow

```
fieldName: {
    validators: {
        remote: {
            url: remoteUrl,
             data: function(validator, $field, value) {
                return {
                    foreignKey: validator.getFieldElements('foreignKey').val()
                };
            },
            type: 'POST',
            message: "This is the message!"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it works for me. 'Id' is dynamically pass for remote method.